# Comparing dates and times in different fields

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Now, I've a problem with the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE date > CURDATE() 
    OR date = CURDATE() 
    AND time > CURTIME()
```

It's return rows with date > of today but I need also rows with date of today but with time > of the  current time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the related clauses inside parenthesis:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE date > CURDATE() 
    OR (
      date = CURDATE() 
      AND time > CURTIME()
    )
```

Comment: thank you very much, I solved it.
It was very simple, I have now learned.
Until next time, good day! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the appropriate date/time functions instead of complicating yourself with complex `WHERE` clauses:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE ADDTIME(date, time) > NOW()
```

More information on the `ADDTIME` function in this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime).